# using django image filed with lightbox

Tags: django, html, lightbox, django-models

I want to use lightbox 
with django .  in my django model i have an image field and lightbox need to load your image in  html tag.
e.x

```
    <a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```

how I can load my image filed in an html  tag

tnx

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `{{ yourmodel.yourimagefield.url }}` is the way to present the image url in your template in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to [user1099913's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259524/using-django-image-filed-with-lightbox#comment-39358310), the way you show an image in a Django template is to create the `<img>` tag, then insert the image URL into the `src=""` attribute. This might do the trick for you:

```
<a href="{{ yourmodel.yourimagefield.url }}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">
  <img src="{{ yourmodel.yourimagefield.url }}">
</a>
```

You'll need to replace `yourmodel.yourimagefield` with the name of your model and the name of your image field respectively.